# Firebase pods not downloading

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I have looked at multiple sites (including `GitHub`), but no matter what I do, It doesn't seem to work. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `cocoapods`, I even did this:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods  

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods  

sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods  

sudo gem install cocoapods 



cd (PROJECT DIRECTORY)  
pod init  
(put cocoapod in podfile)  
pod install
```

But it still doesn't work.

The specific error is `RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.`

After that,

It starts listing `Ruby` `libraries`. Before It was working, but now it isn't. The pod I added was `Firebase/Database`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by first checking my xcodeproj version using
`gem list`

Then, if your version is less than or equal to 15, update it using
`sudo gem update xcodeproj`